# ipython redirect stdout display corruption

Tags: stdout, ipython

I'm developing a system in python, and one functionality I need is the ability to have console output go to both the console and a user-specified file.  This is replicating the Diary function in MATLAB.  I have the following that works perfectly well on both IDLE on windows and python cmdline in ubuntu (this all exists inside a module that gets loaded):

```
class diaryout(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.save = None

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.save.flush()       
            self.save.close()
        except:
            # do nothing, just catch the error; maybe it self was instantiated, but never opened
            1/1
        self.save = None

    def dclose(self):
        self.__del__()

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.save.write(message)

    def dopen(self,outfile):
        self.outfile = outfile
        try:
            self.save = open(self.outfile, "a")
        except Exception, e:
            # just pass out the error here so the Diary function can handle it
            raise e

def Diary(outfile = None):# NEW TO TEST
    global this_diary

    if outfile == None:
        # None passed, so close the diary file if one is open
        if isinstance(this_diary, diaryout):
            sys.stdout = this_diary.terminal    # set the stdout back to stdout
            this_diary.dclose()                 # flush and close the file
            this_diary = None                   # "delete" it
    else:
        # file passed, so let's open it and set it for the output           
        this_diary = diaryout()                 # instantiate
        try:
            this_diary.dopen(outfile)           # open & test that it opened
        except IOError:
            raise IOError("Can't open %s for append!"%outfile)
            this_dairy=none                     # must uninstantiate it, since already did that
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError("Invalid input detected - must be string filename or None: %s"%Diary.__doc__)   
            this_dairy=none                     # must uninbstantiate it, since already did that
        sys.stdout = this_diary                 # set stdout to it
```

Far superior to both IDLE and the plain python cmline, I'm using ipython; herein my problem lies.  I can turn on the "diary" perfectly fine with no error *but* the display on the console gets messed.  The attached screenshot shows this [image: screenshot]. The output file also becomes similarly garbled.  Everything goes back to normal when I undo the redirection with `Diary(None)`.  I have tried editing the code so that it never even writes to the file, with no effect.  It seems almost like something is forcing an unsupported character set or something I don't understand.

Anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Note that IPython has a logging function built in - have a look at the `%logstart` magic function.

Comment: I will look into this.  However, I would like what I'm developing to be independent of ui (i.e. it should NOT require ipython).