# Corrupted / Garbled Output when capturing stdout from IPython

Tags: python, ipython

A similar question was asked here: [ipython redirect stdout display corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962013/ipython-redirect-stdout-display-corruption) , but the answer is not satisfactory.

What I'm trying to do is capture standard output, write it to a PyQt4 QEditText while also sending it to the terminal as normal.

I'm using python 2.7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The problem is that when I embed an IPython terminal inside the program, the terminal output text gets garbled and I lose autocomplete ability.

I was able to reproduce this issue very simply on my Ubuntu machine (the problem doesnt seem to exist on windows).

In my ubuntu termianl:

```
ipython 
import IPython.utils.io
tee = IPython.utils.io.Tee('fds')
```

right here the text gets garbled while simply trying to use the Tee object.

In my program I do things a little differently, but it boils down to overwriting sys.stdout with a custom object and then when write or flush gets called I log the captured text and send it back to the original stdout and the PyQt4 gui.

---

So, is there a way to safely peek at standard out whenever the write or flush command gets called? And is there a way to do this that doesn't break IPython terminals?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the garbled output?

Comment: It looks like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/uQl88.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's due to special encoding for coloring of text in the terminal. Try using 'ipython --classic'.